# Forecasting 75 steps into the future ARIMA(1,1,1) Model EViews

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, econometrics, eviews

Good afternoon,

I have an economics time series of around 3300 daily observations that go over 10 years.

I already developed and ARIMA(1,1,1) Model based on the autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation correlograms and some unit root tests to determine whether it was necessary to differentiate the series or not.

My question is: how do I forecast 75 steps (multi-step forecast) into the future in EViews? Take into account that this would be completely outside of the sample I have (I cannot compare it to anything else), so I basically want to predict the future, although I know forecasting that many steps into the future can be futile and output something without significance.

However, how can I achieve this?

Thank you very much!

P.S.: I'm open to suggestions in other statistical software such as Stata or Minitab if this is impossible to achieve on EViews. Thanks.

Comment: Just set the sample to the period you want to forecast and then compute the forecast. The manual clearly describes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I would use R with the library `forecast` and the function [`auto.arima`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.11/topics/auto.arima) :

```
require(forecast)
m <- auto.arima(X)
forecast(m,h=72)
```

Answer (score 0):

AUTOBOX , a time series package that I have helped to develop , has this feature where the user specifies how many steps and the forecast horizon per step) . It not only generates the forecast but it computes the forecast error and routes the result to a text file.